# Redux-toolkit: state is a proxy inside a createSlice reducer

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to append / update some data in a state array inside of my slice reducers, but when I try to `console.log` the `.projects` array of the state that I am interested in I just get a javascript Proxy. What is going on here (what am I doing wrong)?

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  projects: [],
};

const projectsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'projectsSlice',
  initialState: { ...initialState },
  reducers: {
    addProject(state, action) {
      const { project } = action.payload;
      const newProjects = [project, ...state.projects];

      console.group('add project');
      console.log('project: ', project);
      console.log('state projects: ', state.projects);
      console.log('newProjects: ', newProjects);
      console.groupEnd();

      state.projects = newProjects;
    },
    setProjects(state, action) {
      const { projects } = action.payload;
      state.projects = projects;
    },
    removeProject(state, action) {
      const { projectId } = action.payload;
      const newProjects = [...state.projects].filter((project) => project.id !== projectId);
      state.projects = newProjects;
    },
    updateProject(state, action) {
      const { project } = action.payload;
      const projectIndex = state.projects.findIndex((stateProject) => stateProject.id === project.id);
      const newProjects = [...state.projects].splice(projectIndex, 1, project);

      console.group('updateProject');
      console.log('project: ', project);
      console.log('projectIndex: ', projectIndex);
      console.log('state projects: ', state.projects);
      console.log('newProjects: ', newProjects);
      console.groupEnd();

      state.projects = newProjects;
    },
  },
});

export const { addProject, removeProject, updateProject, setProjects } = projectsSlice.actions;

export default projectsSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Proxy there is the reason you can just mutate state in that reducer and just get an immutable copy in your state - but browsers are really bad at logging proxies.

[per the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#logging-draft-state-values), you can use the `current` export of RTK&immer:

```
const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  initialState: [{ id: 1, title: 'Example todo' }],
  reducers: {
    addTodo: (state, action) => {
      console.log('before', current(state))
      state.push(action.payload)
      console.log('after', current(state))
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: I noticed that the expression JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state)) does the same thing as the current() function, I decided to write it, it might come in handy.

Comment: @OlegAverkov that can be significantly more expensive though, so tread with care.

Comment: @phry i agree, it is better to use the current() function

Answer (score 0):

You need to use current

```
import { current } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
```

and with that, you can reach the current state and work with them and after that, you can send a return in reducer to return new data.

Will looks like this:

```
const referralSlicer = createSlice({
name: 'referral',
initialState: {
  referrals: [],
  currentCard: 0,
} as IReferralSlicer,
reducers: {
  addReferrals(state, { payload }) {
    return {
      referrals: [...state.referrals, payload],
    }
  },
  deleteReferral(state, { payload }) {
    const currentState = current(state)

    return {
      ...currentState,
      referrals: currentState.referrals.splice(payload, 1),
    }
  },
  setCurrentCard(state, { payload }) {
    return {
      referrals: state.referrals,
      currentCard: payload,
    }
  },
},
})
```